Azure AI Agent Service hangs when generating or uploading files through the Assistant
I'm trying to replicate this quickstart from Microsoft official documentation.
Apparently, it works perfectly if I don’t try to generate or upload files through the AI Assistant, as the same expects and I need to implement. In fact, if I run the agent as described in the article above, when I come to the following rows
run = project_client.agents.create_and_process_run(thread_id=thread.id, assistant_id=agent.id)

print(f"Run status: {run.status}.\nRun details: {run}")

, it hangs with RunStatus.IN_PROGRESS for exactly 10 minutes, then it returns status = expired which is consistent with the claim here:

Runs expire ten minutes after creation. Be sure to submit your tool
outputs before the expiration

I checked its status at row 1672 of <conda_env_path>\Lib\site-packages\azure\ai\projects\operations_patch.py:

As stated, if I send a message through the thread object whose content is like "Generate a joke", it works perfectly. If I just change it to "Generate a joke and write it into the joke.txt file", if has the issue above.
I have the same problem if I try uploading files.
I tried using both gpt-4o-mini (2024-07-18) in East US and gpt-4o (2024-05-13) in West US --> same issue.
Concerning my conda environment, I'm using Python 3.12.8 and I have the latest libraries including, of course, of azure-ai-projects 1.0.0b4:
(aaas) C:\Users\mauromi>pip freeze
anyio==4.7.0
argon2-cffi==23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
arrow==1.3.0
asttokens==3.0.0
async-lru==2.0.4
attrs==24.3.0
azure-ai-projects==1.0.0b4
azure-core==1.32.0
azure-identity==1.19.0
babel==2.16.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
bleach==6.2.0
certifi==2024.12.14
cffi==1.17.1
charset-normalizer==3.4.0
colorama==0.4.6
comm==0.2.2
cryptography==44.0.0
debugpy==1.8.11
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
executing==2.1.0
fastjsonschema==2.21.1
fqdn==1.5.1
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.7
httpx==0.28.1
idna==3.10
ipykernel==6.29.5
ipython==8.31.0
ipywidgets==8.1.5
isodate==0.7.2
isoduration==20.11.0
jedi==0.19.2
Jinja2==3.1.5
json5==0.10.0
jsonpointer==3.0.0
jsonschema==4.23.0
jsonschema-specifications==2024.10.1
jupyter==1.1.1
jupyter-console==6.6.3
jupyter-events==0.11.0
jupyter-lsp==2.2.5
jupyter_client==8.6.3
jupyter_core==5.7.2
jupyter_server==2.15.0
jupyter_server_terminals==0.5.3
jupyterlab==4.3.4
jupyterlab_pygments==0.3.0
jupyterlab_server==2.27.3
jupyterlab_widgets==3.0.13
MarkupSafe==3.0.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.7
mistune==3.0.2
msal==1.31.1
msal-extensions==1.2.0
nbclient==0.10.2
nbconvert==7.16.4
nbformat==5.10.4
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
notebook==7.3.2
notebook_shim==0.2.4
overrides==7.7.0
packaging==24.2
pandocfilters==1.5.1
parso==0.8.4
platformdirs==4.3.6
portalocker==2.10.1
prometheus_client==0.21.1
prompt_toolkit==3.0.48
psutil==6.1.1
pure_eval==0.2.3
pycparser==2.22
Pygments==2.18.0
PyJWT==2.10.1
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
python-json-logger==3.2.1
pywin32==308
pywinpty==2.0.14
PyYAML==6.0.2
pyzmq==26.2.0
referencing==0.35.1
requests==2.32.3
rfc3339-validator==0.1.4
rfc3986-validator==0.1.1
rpds-py==0.22.3
Send2Trash==1.8.3
setuptools==75.1.0
six==1.17.0
sniffio==1.3.1
soupsieve==2.6
stack-data==0.6.3
terminado==0.18.1
tinycss2==1.4.0
tornado==6.4.2
traitlets==5.14.3
types-python-dateutil==2.9.0.20241206
typing_extensions==4.12.2
uri-template==1.3.0
urllib3==2.3.0
wcwidth==0.2.13
webcolors==24.11.1
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.8.0
wheel==0.44.0
widgetsnbextension==4.0.13


It is working fine with gpt-4, gpt-40. Try once again with separate venv. Also try creating function tool for this.

I tried with gpt-4,gpt-4o and gpt-4o-mini it is working fine by giving the downloadable link to the file.
Try to create new virtual environment,
install below packages
pip install azure-ai-projects
pip install azure-identity

and try your code.
If anything doesn't work you create a function as tool instead of code interpreter.
Use below code.
import os
from azure.ai.projects import AIProjectClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from typing import Any
from typing import Any, Callable, Set
from azure.ai.projects.models import FunctionTool, ToolSet


def save_file(joke: str) -> str:
    file_name = "joke.txt"
    try:
        with open(file_name, "w") as f:
            f.write(joke)
        return "success: file saved"
    except Exception as e:
        return f"error: {str(e)}"
    
    


user_functions: Set[Callable[..., Any]] = {
    save_file,
}

functions = FunctionTool(user_functions)
toolset = ToolSet()
toolset.add(functions)

project_client = AIProjectClient.from_connection_string(
    credential=DefaultAzureCredential(), conn_str="<conn_str>"
)

Here, i have created a function which takes the input data and writes to the file joke.txt.
Next, create agent,thread and message
agent = project_client.agents.create_agent(
    model="gpt-4", name="my-agent", instructions="You are a helpful agent", toolset=toolset
)
print(f"Created agent, ID: {agent.id}")

thread = project_client.agents.create_thread()
print(f"Created thread, ID: {thread.id}")

message = project_client.agents.create_message(
    thread_id=thread.id,
    role="user",
    content="Generate a joke and save it into the joke.txt file",
)
print(f"Created message, ID: {message.id}")

Create a run
run = project_client.agents.create_and_process_run(thread_id=thread.id, assistant_id=agent.id)
print(f"Run finished with status: {run.status}")

messages = project_client.agents.list_messages(thread_id=thread.id)
for i in messages.text_messages:
    print(i.text)

Output:

and in joke.txt


After a few more tests, it seems that the reason is the region that I choose in the ARM template that Microsoft provides on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/agents/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-python-azure#choose-basic-or-standard-agent-setup (the standard version):

If I choose “West US”, it fails
If I choose “East US”, it works

BTW: in both cases, the Azure AI Services is created in East US (which is the parameter “model location” of the template, independent of the “Region” parameter), which I left by default as “eastus” in both cases.I opened a ticket

Ok is my alternative solution helpful to you?

I have tried in both eastus and westus deployed model, and the ai hub was in eastus,it was working fine

it IS helpfull for sure as a workaround, thank you very much. I'm just trying to understand why it fails on my side, I hope the technical support will help clarifying this.
